# Search engine for linguistic corpus

Tags: lucene, nlp, search-engine, sphinx, information-retrieval

I'm trying to find a good library for building a linguistic corpus search engine. Such an engine must produce absolutely transparent search result (exact numbers of found matches, no result cutting even if the entire corpus matches), basic query syntax (AND, OR, NOT operators, distance search, wildcard search) and the ability of refining the documents set to search in (i.e., setting a subcirous).
An important detail is the ability of index partitioning and performing search in parallel (the size of corpus has the order of 10^8 words, and the search service must be real time).

The main choice is between Sphinx and Clucene (a C++ Lucene port). Unfortunately, I don't know much about these libraries organization, so it would be very helpful to know which one fits my requirements better.

(I've also tried a specialized engine - IMS Corpus Workbench - which turned out not to be as scalable as needed).

Comment: IMS Corpus Workbench with CPQWeb interface is rather buggy. Possibly you can try UPlug http://sourceforge.net/projects/uplug/

Comment: It looks like you want a C++ solution. Otherwise, I would recommend you to try Solr, or ElasticSearch (both java, and both excellent!)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest setting up SOLR server, which is a Lucene derivative and has a Restful interface. The newer features of Lucene(SOLR) are quite unparalleled in other counterparts. A corpus of 10^8 distinct words, maybe a concern, but I hope they are non-distinct. Atmost, in my guess, it may lead to some loss in preformance. Providing partitioning and search in parallel on bare Lucene would be a vestigial effort. SOLR provides both the features.
I am not much aware of Sphinx. But by far, Lucene and its derivatives are on the bleeding edge.